# How can I get ID from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, row

I want to get ID value from mySQL table. 
For example :Get id from Second row or Third row. How can I do this?

```
SELECT Id From myTable --------- ;
```

What is the second row syntax?

Comment: For example, i want to get Id value of second row in my table.

Comment: write limit 1,1 after query. SELECT Id From myTable LIMIT 1,1;

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfect Vipin Jain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch second row then use `LIMIT 2, 1` and if you want 3rd row then use `LIMIT 3, 1`.

Try this:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY Id 
LIMIT 2, 1;
```

Comment: I've got a new problem. When i try SELECT * 
FROM  `myTable` 
LIMIT 1,1 it returns second row but when i try SELECT Id 
FROM  `myTable` 
LIMIT 1,1 it returns 4th row Id value ??

Comment: I changed my syntax to this : SELECT Id
FROM  `mytable` 
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 1 , 1 and it returns correct value now

Comment: @Giray: If you think this answer helped you. Please tick this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find this answer easily. *Thanks*

Comment: Offsets start from 0 **not** 1. That means `LIMIT 2, 1` returns one row starting from **3rd** row. That is why you need to use `LIMIT 1 , 1` to get the 2nd row.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do that...

Return 1 record, start from second record

```
 select id from table_name limit 2,1
```

Fetch 10 records, leave first 15.

```
 SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Write limit 1,1 after query.

```
SELECT Id From myTable LIMIT 1,1;
```